# TeamCity + NUnit + Selenium C# запуск тестов на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, teamcity, nunit

### Автоматические тесты для ASP.NET-MVC-приложения

Проблема следующая: При запуске из TeamCity тесты валятся по непонятным причинам.

Ошибка такая на первых тестах. Остальные тесты проходят. Если поменять порядок тестов, то валятся всегда первые тесты.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63877/session/1b2b0226f81e539ea39ee6645bd179d5/element/ad4c432b-7921-44e4-82e3-30b680d57e62/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

P.S. Если в ручную запустить тесты на сервере, они проходят.

---

Есть агент на TeamCity, который при создании merge request стягивает код МР на сервер, билдит проект, очищает базу данных и публикует её ну и собственно запускает автотесты.

Автоматические тесты написаны с использованием NUnit, в качестве браузера - Chrome.

Шаг на котором запускаются тесты сконфигурирован вот так:

- Runner Type: .Net
- Command: vstest

Запускается всё это дело в консоли вот с такими параметрами:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe Sources\CI\AutomatedTests\HR_DMS_Tests\bin\Release\HR_DMS_Tests.dll /Platform:x86 /logger:logger://teamcity /TestAdapterPath:C:\TeamCity\WindowsBuildAgent\plugins\dotnet\tools\vstest15 /logger:console;verbosity=normal`

Пробовал многое. Вплоть до того, что перешел с MSTest на NUnit. (последнее нужно для параллелизации) Изрядно поигрался с оптимизацией IIS и что я только не пробовал.

---

Comment: Когда то я пвтался настроить автоматическое тестирование на teamcity сервера для настольного приложения и вышло так, что сам агент TeamCity был запущен как сервис, а сервисы не могут работать с UI - то есть открывать окна и кликать по ним. Чтобы эту теорию проверить, я стопанул агента-сервис и запустил его через командную строку от моей учетки - после этого тесты прошли. Можете попробовать повторить, на случае если у вас похожая ошибка.

Comment: хотя судя по `System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: The operation has timed out` - может мой совет и нерелевантен вовсе.

Comment: Привет, спасибо за коммент! С UI всё ок. В моём случае, не проходят только первые запускающиеся тесты. У меня была теория о том, что IIS не вывозит. На сервере развернута локалка и я проверил насколько быстро сервер даёт ответ. В общем он отвечает за 1.2 секунды (самый быстрый ответ), тогда как на моём рабочем ПК ответ приходит за 200-300мс.

Comment: в этом случае вы можете 1) Увеличить timeout 2) Разобраться почему тормозит IIS 3) Если это из за холодного старта, то попробуйте не гасить пул приложений (там можн настроить, чтобы пул никогда не засыпал, если это вам подходит конечно)

Comment: Но вообще таймаут 1 секуда звучит маловато, я бы сделал в минуту или две. Хотя это от ваших требований зависит конечно.

Comment: 1) Увеличивал таймаут. Можете уточнить, таймаут увеличивать пытался при инициализации драйвера в конструкторе ```Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));``` это верно? 2) Не хватает компетенции видимо, не могу разобраться. 3) Разогревал IIS другими тестами. Start mode - AlwaysRunning (так не засыпает вроде)

Comment: Я селениум не знаю, но если у вас падает через минуту, а вы выставили тайм-аут на 5 минут - то вы его выставили не там. Какой тайм-аут у вас на сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причины, по которым следующая инициализация не влияла на таймаут запуска мне не известны.

```
Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Проблема решилась, когда я инициализировал чуть по-другому свой хром драйвер:

```
var outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
return new ChromeDriver(outputDirectory, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

Сделал вывод, что лучше атачиться к конкретному `exe` файлу